# JQuery Treeview Highlight the Background color for the Child Node that is clicked on ASP.NET MVC Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

I have an ASP.NET MVC Page that has Left Menu navigation that is built using JQuery Treeview as in Demo #3 in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/index.htm

Here I made Childnode as href link so that rightside main partial view is loaded.

Now for the chicldnode that is clicked, I want to highlight the background-color.

Wondering how to do this?

Appreciate your time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$(".treeview a").click(function(){ 
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "blue");
});
```

---

**CSS**

What would be better so that you don't have multiple 'blue' background'ed anchor tags is just **extend** their 'selected' class:

```
.treeview a.selected { background: blue; }
```

Comment: I put gray. But The selection background color is remaining. For Example, if i click on first child, its background is turning gray. But if i click on second child, the first one's background color is remaning.

Comment: Did you read my answer? I would recommend not doing this in jQuery. The "selected" node and css class is handled by the treeview plugin already so all you need to do is override the background color of that class like my 2nd example

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick also :-

```
$(".treeview a").click(function ()
 {

      $("a").css("backgroundColor", "");

      $(this).css("backgroundColor", "blue");

 });
```

Its works for me  tested ... 
May b help full for you :::